# Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic not starting GNOME session on bootup

Tags: gnome, 18.10

To better describe the above problem, whenever I start up my Ubuntu/Windows 10 Machine and select Ubuntu, whenever the machine tries to start the GNOME Desktop Environment, it says it started it successfully. however, I never get a graphical desktop environment to use. I can fix this by logging into tty3 and typing `gnome-session` but I don't really want to do that as, for some reason, that skips login. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As its name suggests lightdm is a more lightweight login display manager than gdm3. Switch the login display manager from gdm3 to lightdm. Switching from gdm3 to lightdm will still allow you to login to the GNOME desktop environment as usual.

```
sudo apt install lightdm  
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm   
sudo reboot
```

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` will open up a new window allowing you to select lightdm as the default login display manager. Use the arrow keys to select lightdm, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to put the focus on **<OK>** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then reboot by running `sudo reboot`

Comment: Instead of changing DM's, I'd first try editing `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and un-commenting `#WaylandEnable=false` to disable wayland.