# Stuck at "Started GNOME Display Manager" on 18.10

Tags: boot, system-installation, gdm

I just recently installed Ubuntu 18.10. After successful installation, I rebooted my system but Ubuntu didn't boot, it gets stuck at showing `started GNOME display manager`.

My keyboard is also not working. What is the problem? How can I get a complete Ubuntu desktop ready without any errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic not starting GNOME session on bootup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085296/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-not-starting-gnome-session-on-bootup)

Comment: @karel switching DM's may not be the best solution. Please see my answer.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.10 the wayland session is installed, but it is not used by default.

Comment: @karel actually it is used, and many users with older GPU's can't get past the Ubuntu boot logo with the 5 rotating dots (or gdm3 not starting). Disabling wayland in this way solves that problem and allows the machine to fully boot properly.

Answer (score 6):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a new install of 19.04 on a Windows Hyper-V VM.

I was able to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> to get to the secondary TTY terminal and login and edit this file. Rebooted, and now have access to the GUI-desktop.

Comment: I guess I have the same problem but when I stop holding Alt+F2 the first terminal come back
Can so help me ?