# GNOME Display Manager Ubuntu Boot Issue

Tags: login, display

My ubuntu desktop boots only upto Gnome display manager and does not show login screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic not starting GNOME session on bootup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085296/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-not-starting-gnome-session-on-bootup)

Comment: You will have to be more precise about the problem. The GNOME Display Manager *is* the program that displays the login screen.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a

Comment: I am using Ubuntu  Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy